# Is object facing another

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'd like to derive a value for how much one object is facing another. For example if it is directly facing the value would be 1 and facing directly away -1.
I have the object's global position and a quaternion for orientation. I'm using three.js

This is what I have so far, but its not giving me numbers I would expect.

Storing the object orientation as 3 part vector:

```
const lookVector = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);
const direction = lookVector.clone().applyMatrix4(torsoMesh.matrix);
this.lookVector = direction.sub(this.worldPosition);
```

Then using this to derive an angle to another point:

```
angleTo(pointOfInterest){
    const vectorToPOI =  pointOfInterest.sub(this.worldPosition);
    const angle = this.lookVector.angleTo(vectorToPOI);
    return angle;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to achieve this is using [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). It is very simple, you just normalize both vectors and multiply each component respectively, then sum them up. I won't go into more detail here, because there is loads of resources explaining this on the internet. But here is an example of how to do it in three.js:

```
this.lookVector.normalize();
pointOfInterest.normalize();
var angleValue = this.lookVector.dot(pointOfInterest);
```

this will give exactly what you asked for (just remember that by calling `normalize()` on a vector, you are modifying it).

angleValue is actually just the cosine of the angle between the two vectors, so another way would just be to do:

```
.
.
return Math.cos(angle);
```

hope I understood you question correctly.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that this doesn't take their position into account though?

Comment: @BenGannaway If you want to get the value for how much the `torsoMesh` is facing `pointOfInterest`, you want to take the dot product of the vector pointing from `torsoMesh` to `pointOfInterest` and the vector that is pointing in the direction that `torsoMesh` is facing (both normalized). That will take into account their position relative to eachother. It will not however give you any indication of how far away from eachother they are.

Answer (score 0):

I know the mesh objects keep rotation values in radians. Maybe you can have a "parent mesh" so to speak and its its rotation values to determine this.